# Vulkan Draw Solid Wireframes

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I am trying to implement an object viewer similar to the 3D Viewer of Windows 10 based on Vulkan myself. However, I cannot find a good enough way to draw solid wireframes.

It is easy to draw hollow wireframes, which only needs you to set the `rasterizationInfo.polygonMode` to `VK_POLYGON_MODE_LINE`. After some googling I find two ways to draw a solid wireframe:

1. Pass barycentric coordinates to the vertex shader and set the out color of the fragment shader according to their distances to the lines of the triangular meshes, but this requires deindexing the vertices.
2. Simply draw the lines after drawing the meshes.

I do not want to deindex my vertices so I choose the second approach (more specifically, I used two pipelines to draw indices twice using the same render pass). However, I am struggling with the z-test in complicated shapes. I tried to move every vertex a little bit along their normal when drawing the lines but it does not perform ideally, especially for the triangle lines parallel to the surfaces they lie.

I am wondering if there are any other ways to draw this solid wireframe without deindexing the vertices. Or what is the preferred way to draw solid wireframes.

Here is the result I am not satisfied with based on the model [Viking Room](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/viking-room-a49f1b8e4f5c4ecf9e1fe7d81915ad38)
[image: Resulted solid wireframe of model Viking Room]

Comment: If the issue is depth precision then, for the same line width, I'd expect the barycentrics approach to have the same problem (i.e. the edge of the primitive is missing because a strip of pixels is failing depth testing).

Comment: Also, are they definitely all coincident with the plane? Based on corner positioning, some of the tris look like they are intersecting the floor slightly.

Comment: @solidpixel Thank you. It is a good point that the barycentric approach won't help either. I checked the results of Windows 10 3D Viewer again and find that they also missed some edges. I guess it looks better because it renders shadows as well.

Comment: The depth biasing bodge that I have always found most reliable and portable for decals is to just narrow the camera field of view slightly for the decal pass. Not sure how well it would work for wireframe, but it's relatively straightforward to give it a try.